# How to disable stock lock screen

Tags: lock-screens, lg-g4

I have LG G4 and I am using [Picturesque Lock Screen](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.androidapps.picturesque&hl=en) in place of default Lock Screen. After the last update of Microsoft lock screen things have changed. I have both the lock screens are enabled by default i.e. stock LG one and the Micrsoft one. How would I disable the stock lock screen. I can do anything because I have root access. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you tried to disable Microsoft lockscreen in settings>apps  ..?
If you after that again get two lockscreens, than go to settings>security>lockscreen and set lockscreen security to 'none'.

Comment: Yea it worked now

Comment: It was so stupid of me. I didn't even tweak those settings.

Comment: I'm glad i've helped. Cheers